# Why does git pull keeping complaining about untracked working tree?

Tags: git

I want to update my local code so as usually I do 'git pull', but it gives me this error:

```
 > git pull
    Updating 76dbbae..80dc834
    error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        nlu/lu/tests/test_cases.txt
        nlu/lu/tests/wild.py
        
    Please move or remove them before you merge.
    Aborting
```

Then I usually do checkout to overwrite local changes:

```
git checkout nlu/lu/tests/test_cases.txt
git checkout nlu/lu/tests/wild.py
```

It normally worked but today it keeps giving me this error:

```
error: pathspec 'nlu/lu/tests/test_cases.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Clearly these files have been in the remote repository for a long time. I then tried:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git pull
```

But it didn't help either. I don't know why I got this message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+The+following+untracked+working+tree+files+would+be+overwritten+by+merge

Answer (score 3):

Pay careful attention to the exact wording of this Git error message:<sup>1</sup>

> ```
> error: The following untracked working tree files ...
> ```

Let me add more emphasis: "The following ***untracked*** working tree files".

An *untracked* file, in Git, is one that is in your working tree—i.e., the place where you can see and work on files—but not in Git's *index*.  (See below for more about Git's index.)  In general, a file that's not in Git's index is probably not in your current *commit* either, so:

> ```
> git checkout nlu/lu/tests/test_cases.txt
> error: pathspec 'nlu/lu/tests/test_cases.txt' did not match any
>     file(s) known to git.
> ```

makes sense here.  This is a file *you created* (somehow) in your working tree: it's not a file that *came out of* Git, from the current commit.  You can't make the file in your working tree match the file that's in Git because *it is not in Git* (in the current commit, that is).

Git goes on to say:

> ```
> Please move or remove them before you merge.
> ```

and that is the correct advice: move (to some other file names, or some other directory where Git won't overwrite them) or remove (entirely) these files.  Which to use depends on whether *you* have anything of value *in* these two files.

(The command you'd use to remove a file will depend on your OS.  It might be `rm` or `del` or `remove` or `purge` or something along those lines.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Unfortunately, many Git error messages have poor and/or confusing wording, but you still have to pay close attention anyway.

---

## What's going on here, or, what you need to know about Git before you keep working with Git

Git is not really about *files*, and not really about *branches* either.  What Git is all about is *commits*.  You therefore need to know what a commit is and does for you.  A Git *repository* holds commits, and commits hold files, and you find commits via branch names, but it's really the *commits* that matter.

#### Commits

A Git commit:

- Is numbered: every commit has a unique *hash ID*.  (Git sometimes calls these *object IDs*, and in the past, called them *SHA-1 hashes*.)  When I say *unique* I really mean *unique*.  Every commit you make gets a *different* number than *every other commit that has existed or will ever exist*.<sup>2</sup>
- Is completely read-only, once made.  This plus the hash ID system means that two different pieces of Git software, working with two different repositories, can "meet" and inspect their own repositories and easily discover whether they have the same commits, or different commits, just by comparing the *numbers*.  (Then one Git can give the other one any commits the other commit is missing.)
- Holds two things: a full snapshot of every file, plus some metadata.  The metadata gives information *about* the commit, such as the name and email address of the person who made it.

The *snapshot* is normally the part you care about for getting your work done, but there's a problem with it: it's *completely read only*, and the files inside each commit are stored in a special, compressed-and-de-duplicated form that only Git itself can read.  We'll come back to that in a moment.

The *metadata* are a part Git itself cares about a lot, or at least, one particular item *in* the metadata matter enormously to Git itself.  That one specific item is the fact that Git adds, to each commit, a list of *previous* commit hash IDs.  This list normally has exactly *one* hash ID in it—we won't cover all the exceptions here—and Git calls that one particular hash ID the *parent* of this commit.

Given this fact about a commit, let's draw a commit, replacing the real hash ID (whatever it might be) with a single uppercase letter `H` for *hash*, like this:

```
            <-H
```

The arrow coming out of `H` represents `H`'s stored parent hash ID.  We say that this hash ID *points to* the parent commit.  Let's add to our drawing the parent, using the letter `G` to stand in for this other commit's hash ID:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Note that `G`, too, is a commit, so it too has an arrow sticking out of it, pointing towards *its* parent.  Let's draw that one now:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

What we end up with, in a repository, is a *backwards-looking chain of commits*, ending with your most recent commit—`H` in our example.  As long as Git can find this most-recent commit, Git itself can work backwards, to find *every earlier commit in the chain*.

That is the *history* in the repository, and that's how Git saves every commit you (and anyone else) ever make: each *new* commit points backwards to some *older* commit, which points backwards again, which keeps on pointing backwards, over and over, until we get to the very first commit ever:

```
A <-B <-C ... <-G <-H
```

When we *do* get to that very-first-commit ever, it ends up with an *empty list* of previous commits.  It doesn't point backwards any further because it can't: there was no earlier commit.  So that's where `git log` finally gets to stop, after it starts at the end of history, and works its way all the way backwards to the beginning of history.

Note that as `git log` does this hop-backwards-one-commit-at-a-time trick, it gains access to *every snapshot*, one pair at a time:

```
... <-F <-(G <-H)
```

Git can extract *both* snapshots and compare them, and whatever files are exactly the same (and thus de-duplicated) didn't change and the files that are different (and hence *not* de-duplicated between `G` and `H`) have some difference, which Git can compute and show you.  Then Git moves back one hop:

```
... <-(F <-G) <-H
```

Git can extract *both* snapshots and compare them, and ... well, you should get the idea here.

**This is almost all there is in a repository.**  But there's one little hitch: in order to *find* all these commits, Git needs a fast way to find the *last* commit.  This is where your branch names (and other names) come in.

---

<sup>2</sup>This is mathematically impossible, and Git is doomed to fail someday.  The sheer *size* of the hash ID space puts off that day as long as possible: billions of centuries, we hope.  The old SHA-1 hash turned out to be too small, which is why Git is moving away from SHA-1, which is in turn why Git no longer calls these "SHA-1 hash IDs".

---

#### Branch and other names help you and Git find commits

If we were to use Git without branch and tag and remote-tracking names and the like, we would have to memorize hash IDs.  That would really suck, so Git sets things up so that we can use *names* instead.

A *branch* name is simply a way to store *one* commit hash ID.  We say that the branch name *points to* a commit, much like the way each commit points backwards to some earlier commit.  But there's one key difference:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

Here, the *name* `main` points to `H`, and `H` points to `G` which points to `F` and so on.  But I've stopped drawing the arrows between commits *as* arrows, and there are a couple of reasons for that: laziness, plus a font problem I'm about to run into, plus the fact that these arrows are *part of* a commit, and *no part of any commit can ever change*.  So commit `H` is going to point to earlier commit `G` *forever*.  Nothing, not even Git itself, can change this.

But if we make a *new* commit while we are "on" branch `main`, the arrow *in* the name `main` *will* change.  It will point to our new commit.  Let's run some Git commands to make a new commit:

```
git switch main     # or git checkout main; use if we're not already "on" main
<edit some files>
git add <updated files>
git commit -m "very bad commit message"
```

Git will, at this point, make a *totally new*, never-seen-before commit, which gets an all-new never-used-before hash ID.  We'll just call this "commit `I`" for short though.  New commit `I` will point back to existing commit `H`:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I
```

and now Git will *move the name `main`* (by changing its arrow) so that it points, not to `H` any more, but to `I`:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- main
```

We can, if we like, create a *new branch* before we do all of this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop, main
```

Note that both names—`develop` and `main`—point to the *same commit* `H`, at this point.  When we run `git switch develop` to get "on" branch `develop`, nothing else changes, but now Git knows that the *current branch name* is `develop`.  To keep track of this in our drawings, let's attach the special name `HEAD` to exactly one branch name:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), main
```

Now when we make our new commit `I`, Git will update the *name to which `HEAD` is attached*, and not any other name:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

This is how branch names work in Git: you select one (with `git checkout` or `git switch`) to get "on" that branch, using its *latest* commit.  Then you make a *new* commit and Git adds the new commit to the repository—the collection of all commits, plus the names that help you find *particularly interesting* commits—and updates the one branch name that you're "on".

#### The problem with read-only, frozen-for-all-time snapshots

I mentioned several times above that all Git commits are frozen for all time.  That includes the snapshot-of-all-files.  But we can't work with a file that we can't *read*, and only *Git* can read these frozen snapshots.  Furthermore, we can't get any *new* work done at all unless we can *write* to the files.

All version control systems have this as a problem, and there's a standard solution, which Git uses: the frozen-for-all-time *commits* aren't what you work on/with.  Instead, when you "check out" some commit (with `git checkout` or `git switch`), Git *extracts* all the files *from* that commit into a work area.  This work area is your *working tree* or *work-tree*.

*These* files are ordinary files.  They are readable and writable, and you can do anything you want with them after they've been extracted.  They're *yours*, to use as you like.  Importantly, they are *not in Git*.  Sure, they came *out* of a commit, but they're not *in* a commit now.  Commits hold weird frozen Git-ized files, not ordinary files.  So these aren't in commits, and they're not in Git at all.

If Git were like most other version control systems, Git would stop here, with the two copies of each file: the frozen one, and the usable one.  When you went to make a new commit, Git would scan your working tree and figure out which files you updated and use those to make the new commit.  But Git is weird.  It does not do this at all.  Instead, what Git does is this:

- It has the current (or `HEAD`) commit, with all the frozen files frozen.  They're Git-ified and cannot be removed or changed or anything.
- But then, it has a "copy" of each of these files, which it has placed in something Git calls the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—this term is rare these days—the *cache*.  This copy is in the frozen *format* but isn't actually frozen.  In particular, Git can *remove* this copy (from the index) and stick in a new updated one, or stick all-new-files into the index, or just remove files from the index entirely.

  The `git add` command is (mainly) how you update Git's index.  This command tells Git: *make the index copy of some file(s) match the working tree copy*.  That is, you'll edit the working tree copy of some file, and then before you run `git commit` you must also run `git add`.  Git will:

  - read the working tree copy;
  - compress it into the de-duplicated format;
  - check to see if it's a duplicate; and
  - update the index appropriately.

  The index copy either gets replaced with the updated one (which is or isn't a duplicate and is automatically de-duplicated appropriately), or if this file name is all-new, the index copy gets a new file (which is still de-duplicated appropriately).  Note: `git add` will "add" a *removal* too, so if you *remove* the working tree copy and run `git add` on that file, Git will remove the index copy at that point.  This way the index copy of the file matches the working tree copy, even to the extent of not existing at all if needed.
- Finally, Git provides (on initial `git checkout` or `git switch`) the usable copy of each file, which except for being a *usable* file, matches the index and frozen copy.<sup>3</sup>

Note that this idea of removing-and-replacing the three "active" copies of each file is *how* `git switch` or `git checkout` makes it so that you're working with the right set of files.  Once we have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

for instance, if you switch back to `main`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
            \
             I   <-- develop
```

Git removes, from your working tree and its index, all the commit-`I` copies of all files, and replaces them with commit-`H` files.<sup>4</sup>  (Git doesn't have to do anything with the *committed* files other than attach the name `HEAD` to the name `main`, so that the current *branch* is `main` and the current *commit* is commit `H` now.)

---

<sup>3</sup>There are some tricks Git can play here with CRLF line endings and with "smudge" filters, but we'll ignore these.

<sup>4</sup>As an important optimization, Git *doesn't bother* changing out files that are the same in the two commits.  This means if you `git switch` from branch `br1` to branch `br2` *and* `br1` and `br2` select the *same commit*, Git won't bother with a remove-and-replace on *any* file, since all files in the commit by definition match the same files in the same commit.  You don't have to remember this now, but it becomes useful later, when you find a need to create a new branch after you've started working.  (This happens to everyone all the time.)

---

#### Cloning, remotes, and remote-tracking names

If you create a new Git repository completely from scratch, you won't have anyone else's commits in it at all, but most of the time we mostly start with someone else's repository, using `git clone`, as in:

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git
```

for instance.  This operation:

1. makes a new empty repository (that has *no* commits and *no* branches in it) (this generally takes two commands, only one of which is a Git command);
2. adds a *remote* to that repository: a remote is just a short name that, among other things, holds a URL.  In this case, Git will add the remote name `origin` and store the URL we typed in;
3. does any other necessary configuration;
4. runs `git fetch origin` *in* the new repository; and finally
5. runs `git checkout` *in* the new repository.

The `git fetch origin` step has your Git software call up some other Git software—in this case, on `github.com`, but anything that speaks Git protocol will suffice—and has them connect to some other repository, which presumably has lots of commits.  Their Git software, using their repository—let's call this "their Git" for short—lists out the *last* commits on each of *their* branch names.  Your Git checks to see if you have those commits, and of course you don't, because your new repository is totally empty.  So your Git asks their Git for *those* commits.  They're now obligated to offer the parents of those commits, which your Git will ask for too, and that makes them offer the parents of the parent, and so on.  The end result of all of this is that your Git asks their Git for *every commit they have*.

They send over all their commits (along with the supporting internal objects that store the files and such) and you now have, in your repository, a *copy* of *every commit that they have*.  You, however, have *no branches*.  All you have are their *commits*.

Your Git now takes each of their *branch* names—`main` or `master`, for instance, and `dev` or `develop`, and so on—and *renames* these.  To keep these names separate from *your* branches, your Git names each of these `origin/main`, `origin/dev`, and so on: your Git sticks `origin/` in front of each of their names.  These are your *remote-tracking names*.

Your Git writes out all these names and the corresponding commit hash IDs, and that gives your Git an easy way to find *all* the commits, using these names instead of branch names.  The clone is almost done and your Git can disconnect from their Git at this point.  Now your Git does the last step: it *creates one branch name* in your repository, and checks out the commit at the end of this branch.

The branch name your Git uses here is the one you gave on the command line: `git clone -b dev ssh://git@github.com/...` for instance.  But if you *didn't* give a name—and we didn't—your Git has asked their Git which name *they recommend*.  For GitHub, they'll recommend the branch that someone configured with the GitHub web interface.  If nobody configured anything, they'll probably recommend `main` or `master` (depending on which one they have).  Your Git will *create this name* in your repository, making it point to the *same* commit as your `origin/` variant of this name.

You now have all of their commits and *one* branch name in your own repository.  Your Git now fills in your index and working tree from the one commit your one branch name selects.  Those are the files you have to work on/with, in the usual way.

#### Untracked files

Above, we mentioned *untracked* files, as we saw the error message say the phrase.  But what exactly *is* an untracked file?  Let's go back to the "three copies of every file" model:

- There's the `HEAD`-commit file, which you can't change.
- There's Git's index copy, which you can replace with `git add`.
- There's a working tree copy, which you can do anything you want with.

But hold on a moment: the working tree *is* an ordinary folder (directory) on your computer, in which *you* can *create* any file or folder you like, and create sub-files, and remove files, and so on.  What happens if you create a *new* file that wasn't in the commit that you checked out?

Well, that's pretty obvious: you now have a file in your working tree that *isn't* in Git's index and *did not* come out of any commit.  The important part here, as far as Git is concerned, is the first part: **This file is not in Git's index.**  (You can't change any *committed* file so Git doesn't have to care about whether it came out of some commit, only about whether it's in the index.)

This kind of file is an *untracked file*.  It doesn't matter *how* it got into your working tree, and it doesn't matter *how* it got *out* of Git's index.  You could run:

```
git rm --cached some-file-that-came-out-of-the-commit
```

which tells Git *remove the index copy but leave the working tree copy alone*.  That would give you a file in your working tree that's not in Git's index.  That would be an *untracked file*, by definition.

So that gives us a clear way to know which files are *tracked*—they're the ones that *are* in Git's index—and which ones are *untracked*.

#### Why we have to care about tracked files

When you run `git commit`, Git makes a new commit.  Git *gets the files for the snapshot* out of its index.  Whatever is in Git's index *right now*, when you run `git commit`, *those* are the files that will go into the new commit.  Git doesn't commit the files that are in your working tree.<sup>5</sup>  Instead, Git commits what's in the index.  **The index holds your proposed next commit.**  You update this with `git add`, and then run `git status` to make sure you've got the correct updates in it.

When you do run `git status`, Git will tell you about untracked files, if you have any.  If you *meant* to add and commit them, this gives you the chance to do that.  If you want to get Git to *shut up* about these files, that's what `.gitignore` is for, but `.gitignore` gets a little complicated, and this answer is already quite long, so we'll stop here.

---

<sup>5</sup>You *can* run `git commit -a`, and some people like to do this, but it's a trap: it never adds any *untracked* files and people who do this find themselves forgetting to `git add` *new* files.  You should generally avoid `git commit -a`.  Learn `git add -u` instead: run `git add -u`, then `git status`, and *then* `git commit` if there aren't any untracked files you still need to add.  (The `-a` option to `git commit` is a lot like running `git add -u` first, although there are a bunch of small but important technical differences that we will ignore here for space reasons.)