# git restore --staged vs git rm --cached

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I have read about [git restore vs git rm --cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65434544/whats-the-difference-between-git-rm-cached-git-restore-staged-and-gi), but my question does not ask about the result of the above commands.

I used both Pycharm and Visual Studio Code to coding, and I realize there is a little difference.

On Pycharm, I can use `git restore --staged`  to undo `git add` but on Visual Studio raise a error **fatal: could not resolve HEAD**

Example: I created two files and staging them with git add

[image]

And then, I want to use git restore --staged to unstaged one of two files, but raise a error.

[image]

I try `git restore --staged`  on pycharm, it worked fine

[image]

git restore --staged work fine

[image]

I don't want to urge about which one to use unstage file, I just want to know why there is a difference on Pycharm and Visual Studio Code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are entirely different commands:

- `git restore` is about *copying* some file(s) from somewhere to somewhere.
- `git rm` is about *removing* some file(s) from somewhere.

Because `git restore` is about *copying* a file or files, it needs to know *where to get the files*.  There are three possible sources:

- the current, or `HEAD`, commit (which must exist); or
- any arbitrary commit that you specify (which must exist); or
- Git's *index* aka *staging area*.

Because `git rm` is about *removing* a file or files, it only needs to know the name(s) of the file(s) to remove.  Adding `--cached` tells `git rm` to remove these files *only* from Git's index aka *staging area*.

> On Pycharm, I can use git restore --staged to undo git add but on Visual Studio [I get the] error `fatal: could not resolve HEAD`

This error message indicates that you have no commits.  That means there's no source from which to restore the file *unless* you choose the existing staging area as the source.  So either there's a bug in VSCode (which is extremely likely<sup>1</sup>), or you have not yet made your first commit (which is even more likely).  Your PyCharm IDE is probably able to do things because you *have* made your first commit by now.

This is also what your screenshots show.

---

<sup>1</sup>VSCode is ridiculously complicated *and* allows nearly arbitrary plug-in extensions, and judging by what I have seen here on SO, most of the extensions are positively riddled with bugs.  That's not exactly VSCode's fault, but it's the kind of thing that would make me think again about using VSCode, if I could stand to use IDEs for any serious work in the first place.

Comment: Amazing, Thanks for your detailed explaination. It helps me better understand what i have read about the unstage file. Thank you so much.

Comment: So, I have a question about **current** in **the current, or HEAD, commit (which must exist); or** on your answer. I think it is working directory, what exactly it is, can you describe it more clearly?

Comment: The working directory is not a commit. For (much) more about this, see any of my many more-detailed relatively-introductory Git answers, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71685386/1256452).

Comment: thank you! I need more time to understand it